# Process tree using fork()

Tags: process, c, fork, tree

I am given the task of creating this process tree in C using `fork`, `if` and `else`:

```
|_____1___
|___2__   |
|_4_   |  |_3_
|   |  |  |   |
```

Or as a `pstree` like drawing:

```
p(0)─┬─p(1)───p(3)
     ├─p(2)
     └─p(4)
```

Is this code correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    if(fork()){
        // 1
        if(fork()){
            // 2
            if(fork()){
                // 4
            }
            else{}
        }
        else{}
    }
    else{
        if(fork()){
            // 3}
        else{}
    }

    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. This is clearly a homework problem: what were you give, and what do you have to find?

Comment: Hmm - i need to programme this process tree using only fork()

Comment: Hi. It does not help if you use a non standard way to make a graph. Have a look at the output of `pstree -ap` to see how PIDs and relations are normaslly displayed. Also: Can't you just print out the pid that is returned by `fork`? You could use `pstree` to check your assumptions.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think that our lecturer need to specify what he wants from us :) I have to create a process tree using fork() and if, else in C. The proc tree have to look like is shown above.

Comment: Here is similar problem but different process tree. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082775/using-fork-to-create-process-tree-in-c

Comment: Added a `pstree` like drawing. Is it correct? If not [edit] question and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

OK I understand your question now. Your answer is correct. All I will say is that you can just do

```
fork()
```

for the final `fork`s instead of

```
if (fork()) {}
else {}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate The order of what?

Comment: No it can't. Besides the numbers don't matter -- only the structure of the tree.

Comment: Guess we're talking past each other. The point is that there is no guarantee 3 is forked before 4.

Comment: I don't think that diagram is meant to have a timeline to it. Whether 3 or 4 is forked first, the tree structure will be the same.

Comment: Yes, guess not. But then there is those dangling lines. Are those the forks and the `pstree` drawing wrong? (I added that one but perhaps I should not have. Did it as comments does not support that kind of drawings ...)

Comment: The only way to know what exactly the original drawing was intended to represent is to ask the professor :D I think the lines are confusing and your `pstree` drawing is better. The best way to visualize a process tree is as, well, a tree!

Comment: Yes ... we'll have to wait in anticipation for an update.

Comment: Ach. The update seems to never arrive. Was looking forward to this ...